# Download all files from specific folder on FTP to local folder

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to download all files located within a specific folder on a FTP site. The folder is called `"In"` (as shown in example code) and contains a number of .txt files.

When I run the below code it lists the four .txt files located in the FTP folder `"ftp3.example.com/Jaz/In/"`, however it does not copy them to the target folder of `"C:\Users\Jasdeep\Destination\"`

Note: The list appears for a split second and then PowerShell closes.

Please see screenshot which shows output list
[image: List Example]

I have granted full permissions to the folders and contents on FTP Site.

Could someone please advise where I am going wrong?

```
$ftp = "ftp://ftp3.example.com/Jaz/In/" 
$user = 'username' 
$pass = 'password'
$folder = "/"
$target = 'C:\Users\Jasdeep\Destination'

$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
    $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
}

$folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

$Allfiles=Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials
$files = ($Allfiles -split "`r`n")

$files 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
$counter = 0
 foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.*"})){
    $source=$folderPath + $file  
    $destination = $target + $file 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source, (Join-Path $target $file))

    $counter++
    $counter
    $source
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. But you have too many slashes in the URL, so maybe your particular server cannot handle that.

Your download URL is like

```
ftp://ftp3.example.com/Jaz/In////test2.txt
```

Change the code to:

```
$folderPath = "ftp://ftp3.example.com/Jaz/In/"
```

---

The second problem is this:

```
$files = ($Allfiles -split "`r`n")
```

You rely on the server to return the listing with CR+LF EOL. That's true, only if you make the server use ASCII mode:

```
$request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
$request.UseBinary = $False
```

Or, as a quick hack specific to your particular FTP server, expect LF only:

```
$files = ($Allfiles -split "`n")
```

---

In any case, *"The list appears for a split second and then Powershell closes."* indicates that you didn't really debug the problem. Run your script from existing `cmd.exe` or PowerShell console window, to see its full output, including any error.

Comment: Apparently this does not work: `($Allfiles -split "\`r\`n")` - try only `\`n`

Comment: `Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request." 
At C:\Users\Jas\Desktop\scripting\FTPMultiDownload.ps1:36 char:5 
+       $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file) 
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
      + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException 
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException 

1 
ftp://ftp3.example.com/Jaz/In/test2.txt 
test4.txt 
test3.txt 
test5.txt`

Comment: That worked perfectly! thank you so much. Are you able to explain why that wasn't working please?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Though, in general, your question is duplicate.